# Varchar to Datetime in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion

How can I convert date and time value stored like

> 20200406151341

to DATETIME value 2020/04/06 15:31:41 (YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS.000)? I am unable to find suitable CONVERT() format and the only way so far is to parse the VARCHAR like below.

```
select dateadd(second, cast(substring('20200406151341',13,2) as int),dateadd(minute, cast(substring('20200406151341',11,2) as int), dateadd(hour,cast(substring('20200406151341',9,2) as int),convert(datetime, left('20200406151341',8), 112)))).
```

It works yet it's hard to read and understand especially when I have to use it within SELECT statement multiple times.

Also I am surprised query with above conversions is as fast the one with dates stored directly in DATETIME format. Does MSSQL server uses some kind of cache so it does have to do the conversion only once per row?

I use MSSQL Server 2016.

Comment: Keep your `substring`s, but put them inside a [`datetimefromparts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). `I am surprised query with above conversions is as fast` - calculating scalars in the final select after the rows have been found is extremely fast.

Comment: The best thing to do is to store datetime values with the datatime data type. If you can't change the structure, then I would suggest making a computed column in your table.

Comment: Or use a view - and be prepared to handle values that are cannot be converted. This is what happens when the schema is not given much thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a built in, simple way to do this.

You don't have to go to `second`s to do this.  You can easily convert the first 8 characters to a date.  With some string manipulation, you can convert the last six to a time -- and then add time (as `datetime` values):

```
select convert(datetime, left(dt, 8)) + convert(datetime, stuff(stuff(right(dt, 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':'))
from (values ('20200406151341')) v(dt);
```

You can also use arithmetic rather than 3 `dateadd()`s:

```
select dateadd(second,
               right(dt, 2) + 60*substring(dt, 11, 2) + 60*60*substring(dt, 9, 2),
               convert(datetime, left(dt, 8)))
from (values ('20200406151341')) v(dt)
```

Note:  This uses implicit conversion from a string to an integer (as does your version).

Comment: Thank you stuff is way to go and I also like the arithmetic version

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stuff()` :

```
select convert(datetime, 
               stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(col, 9, 0, ' '), 10, 0, ''), 12, 0, ':'), 15, 0, ':'
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's throw in a couple more options to the mix:

```
DECLARE @StrDate varchar(14) = '20200406151341'

SELECT  DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
            LEFT(@StrDate, 4), -- year
            SUBSTRING(@StrDate, 5, 2), -- month
            SUBSTRING(@StrDate, 7, 2), -- day
            SUBSTRING(@StrDate, 9, 2), -- hour
            SUBSTRING(@StrDate, 11, 2), -- minute
            SUBSTRING(@StrDate, 13, 2), -- second
            0 -- millisecond
        ) As [Using DateTimeFromParst],

        CONVERT(DateTime, LEFT(@StrDate, 8), 112) + -- Date
        CONVERT(DateTime, STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(@StrDate, 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':'), 114) -- Time
        As [Using convert and stuff]
```

Results:

```
Using DateTimeFromParst     Using convert and stuff
2020-04-06 15:13:41         2020-04-06 15:13:41
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [try_convert()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [try_cast()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in case your strings are invalid, and if invalid they will return `NULL` instead of raising an error. Refer to the links for further detail on these functions.

```
declare @val varchar(20) 
set @val = '20200416151341'

select try_convert(datetime, 
           stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(@val, 9, 0, ' '), 10, 0, ''), 12, 0, ':'), 15, 0, ':')
              );


select try_cast(
           stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(@val, 9, 0, ' '), 10, 0, ''), 12, 0, ':'), 15, 0, ':')
              as datetime);
```